# nginx rewrites with several variables and rules

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I'm dealing with Nginx rewrite rules to have SEO friendly addresses, at the moment I've just tried with one `GET` variable and just one rule. My config is:

```
location / {         
    rewrite ^/request-account/(.*)$ /request_account.php?id=$1 last;
}
```

this transforms the `request_account.php?id=XXX` into `/request-account/XXX`

But I would like to add more rewrite rules with more than one `GET` variable

E.g.

```
request_user.php?id=ab12&page=23
```

Also, should I write `break` or `last` at the end of the rewrite rule? I've been reading this affects the efficiency of Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to concatenate the other GET variables you can do that by appending `$args`

```
rewrite ^/request-account/(.*)$ /request_account.php?id=$1&$args last;
```